# python - Get dynamic JavaScript value from selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The X and Y value changes when I move the cursor.

[I am able to get the X axis value as there is an element in the script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDXsD.png)

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "stx-float-date.floatDate").text
```

But the Y values is updated through JavaScript and I am not able to return the value. There are 2 functions used to get and display the value but I am not able to read the value.

[Function to calculate the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzPE2.png)

```
driver.execute_script("""return z7L""")
driver.execute_script("""return window.z7L""")
driver.execute_script("return transformedPriceFromPixel()")
```

[Function to display the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjB7e.png)

```html
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='stx-float-price']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
driver.execute_script("return q$v.ChartEngine.prototype.updateFloatHRLabel()")
```

I have even tried using Local storage but the variables are not stored there

```
driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage;")
```

Comment: Is the url a public url? Can you update the question with the exact manual steps?

Comment: It is not a public URL. There is 2 Factor authentication involved and log's in to a trading website. I have completed that part using Selenium including running the third party apps to get TOTP. I am able to scrape the data and access all tools inside the URL but require the Y co-ordinates to do further processing. https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/ciq/NSE/AARTIIND/1793